# Class android.location.Location does not define a no-argument constructor xx

Tags: java, android, firebase

I have a trouble in Firebase and package Location

com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class android.location.Location does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

```
private void readChanges() {
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Location location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Location.class);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

And i have error :
Process: com.example.coffeebakeryfordriver, PID: 15287
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class android.location.Location does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.

Comment: The error message that you get clearly says what the issue is. So please check the duplicate to see how you can solve this, by adding the no-argument constructor to your `Location` class.

Comment: `Vitri location = dataSnapshot.getValue(Vitri.class);
                        if (location != null) {
                            myMaker.setPosition(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                        }`

Comment: And i fixed this. Because Location no argument on Firebase. Tks for your comment @AlexMamo

Comment: You're very welcome.